# Cannot assign CGPoint to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

```
var touchPoint = gestuRerecognizer.locationInView(self.map)
var newCoordinate = map.convertPoint(touchPoint, fromCoordinateSpace: self.map)
var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
```

This code gives me (**Cannot assign a value of type 'CGPoint' to a value of type 'CLLocationCoordinate2D'**) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
let newCoordinate = map.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView:self.map)
annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
```

Instead of:

```
var newCoordinate = map.convertPoint(touchPoint, fromCoordinateSpace:self.map)
```

because it is returning you a `CGPoint`, not a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which causes the error when you assign `newCoordinate` to `annotation.coordinate`.

Comment: this method not available in lated google sdk , what should be the alternative way ?